# Passing HTML Markup into RazorEngine in a Console Application

Tags: c#, html, templates, razor

I'm attempting to use RazorEngine 3 to insert HTML elements into a template. When I try this, the resulting string (used later as HTML) ends up displaying the HTML markup rather than utilizing it to render the page.

**Code:**

```
var linkText = new HtmlString("<a href=" + location + ">" + linkName + "</a>");
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new {MyLink = linkText});
```

**Template file:**

```
Link to file: @Model.MyLink
```

**Resulting HTML:**

```
Link to file: <a href=http://blah.com>Blah link</a>
```

This functionality was working fine with RazorEngine 2, but I had to upgrade due to another glitch. Additionally, this is a console application so adding @Raw functionality might be complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ended up being to use a string type variable that is passed into the template. The template, in turn uses the Raw() method as seen below.

**Code:**

```
string linkText = "<a href=" + location + ">" + linkName + "</a>";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new {MyLink = linkText});
```

**Template File:**

```
Link to file: @Raw(@Model.MyLink)
```